# When I trying to print Text value (realtime fetch value) of Flutter Cards and It always print final card value.. How Can I fix this in Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to set my firetore real-time data into Card widget and print the Text value of each Card On OnTap function. But It always prints the final value of the card, not each card value.

[image: I am trying to print "Alert New" but always print the final value of the card.]

In this image, I am trying to print "Alert New" but always print the final value of the card.

Here is my code.

```
class _LoadDataState extends State<LoadData> {
  //Read Data in realTime Snapshot
  final Stream<QuerySnapshot> _cupCakeStream = FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('cupcake')
      .snapshots(includeMetadataChanges: true);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: _cupCakeStream,
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Text('Something went wrong');
        }

        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return Text("Loading");
        }

        return Container(
          child: ListView(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            children: snapshot.data!.docs.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
              Map<String, dynamic> data =
                  document.data()! as Map<String, dynamic>;
              listDocID = document.id;

              return Card(
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12)),
                child: new InkWell(
                  onTap: () {
                    print(cupcakeName.data); //Trying to Print Data
                  },
                  child: Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
                    child: Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        cupcakeName = Text(
                          data['cupcake_name'],
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 20,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                   );
                 }).toList(),
                );
               }
              }
```

How can I fix this...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `print(cupcakeName.data);` with `print(data['cupcake_name']);`

`cupcakeName` value is always updated to the `Text` widget (therefore will always have the value of the last `Text` widget).